# Having Open MPI related issues while making CUDA 5.0 samples (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: cuda, makefile, ubuntu-12.04, openmpi

```
Makefile:79: *** MPI not found, not building simpleMPI..  Stop.
```

this error is the error im getting...
I saw the Mac version of this question but im using Ubuntu 12.04.
Does anyone know how to fix this on Ubuntu 12.04?
thanks for any help!

Comment: Install MPI or skip the example.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't installed all the dependencies to build CUDA Samples. Install MPI before building the samples by using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install mpi-default-dev
```

Refer to [this guide](http://www.r-tutor.com/gpu-computing/cuda-installation/cuda5.0-ubuntu) for the list of dependencies for CUDA Samples.